# Assigning values to certain components of an array rather than the whole array

Tags: arrays, c

When I want a function returning an array I can use pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* integers(int size)
{
   int* integers_array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
   for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
   {
      integers_array[j]=j;
   }
   return integers_array;
}
```

But what if, for example, I already have an array `x` and I want to assign new values to all its components except the first 2?
I would like to do it with address arithmetic, but I cannot do the following

```
x+2=integers_array(4);
```

because I can't have an expression on the left hand side of an assignment. So far, the way I dodge the issue is to create an assignment `void` function:

```
void assignment(int size, int in_array[], int out_array[])
{
   for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
   {
      out_array[j]=in_array[j];
   }   
}
```

when I do this, the `void` function works with address arithmetic, meaning that I can do the following:

```
int main()
{
    int size=4;
    int* y;
    int x[]={1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    y=integers(size);
    assignment(size, y, x+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Without creating a `void` function. What is the proper syntax to assign values only to a portion of an array, from a function?

Comment: You can do x[2] = integers_array[4]; if you wanted to.

Comment: Your `assignment` function resembles `memcpy`/`memmove` functions a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … I can't have an expression on the left hand side of an assignment.

The left side of an assignment may be an expression, but it must be an *lvalue*, which `x+2` is not.

To set `n` elements of array `x` starting at offset `o` elements from the beginning of the array to values from the same type of elements of array `y` (starting at the beginning of `y`), you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(x+o, y, n * sizeof *x);
```

If the movement is within the same array and may overlap, use `memmove` instead of `memcpy`.

Other than that, to change portions of an array, expect to write your own loops, whether you encapsulate them in a function or not. C is not a language designed to provide many compound functions or automatic management of complicated types.